# react-redux unable to dispatch action onchange of inputext

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to trigger an action defined in another file based on the text entered in input text. But I keep on getting error `Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.onChange is not a function`. I am new to react so any help is kindly appreciated.

My component js file is as follows:

```
import React, { Component, bindActionCreators } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { searchperson } from '../actions/person-actions';

class PersonSearch extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);          
    this.searchInputChange = this.searchInputChange.bind(this);

    }
  searchInputChange(event) {
    searchperson(event.target.value);
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" className="search-input" onChange={(event) => this.props.onChange(event.target.value)} />

      </div>
    )
  }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      onChange: (name) => {
          dispatch(searchperson(name)) // Need the input v alue here
      }
  }
}

connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PersonSearch)

export default PersonSearch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if prop `onChange` is defined, you may want to do this:

`<input type="text" className="search-input" onChange={this.searchInputChange} />`

And in `searchInputChange` method, perhaps you can invoke `onChange` prop, like so:

```
searchInputChange(event) {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
}
```

And remember to export connected component, like so:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PersonSearch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With the suggested change the error shifts to searchInputChange function `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onChange is not a function
    at PersonSearch.searchInputChange (person-search.js:13)`

Comment: just noticed, you may need to export the connected component ```export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PersonSearch)``` - Updated my answer

Comment: gr8 this was the missing piece. On export defaulting my connect function the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot